# How Grails gorm will insert table per concrete class where each concrete class inherits an abstract class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi all following is the situation
I have an abstract class AbstractProfile and one concrete class GoogleProfile

```
abstract class AbstractProfile  {
    .....
}

class GoogleProfile extends AbstractProfile { 

    ......
}
```

I am using grails but gorm is not inserting table for google profile current gorm is inserting table for only AbstractProfile class please help Thanks in advance

Comment: The grails version i am using is 2.0.4

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging and found out that starting on [grails 2.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20131114094834/http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2759) you have the following mapping option:

```
tablePerConcreteClass true
```

It seems the documentation (even for version [2.4](https://web.archive.org/web/20170602021421/http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceStrategies)) hasn't been updated regarding this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
abstract class BaseDomain {
            static mapping = {
                tablePerConcreteClass true
                id generator: 'increment'
                version false
            }
    }
```

Comment: add a little bit of explanation to this code will be helpful for future readers.

Comment: To avoid creating a base_domain table I also needed tablePerHierarchy: false. I found the advantage to using tablePerConcreteClass instead of putting the base domain class in src to be that I could index columns in the base domain class.

Comment: @gabe thanks I have created an ansswer here explaining what you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447280/equivalent-of-inheritancetype-table-per-class-in-grails/45209432#45209432 - as a point of reference for others

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.0 persists abstract classes. In order to enable an individual table to the extending class, you need to specify:

```
static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy       false
}
```

to the abstract class. Otherwise the whole hierarchy will "live" in the same table.

Comment: static mapping = {
  tablePerHierarchy:false
} Hello heikkim i have inserted this mapping to my Abstract class but still same result

Comment: You have an extra colon in the definition, between "tablePerHierarchy" and "false".

Comment: Thanks heikkin it works for me but now when i want to save an instance of google profile to db following is generated       | Error 2012-08-03 12:52:41,748 [pool-15-thread-2] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in com.test.demo.GoogleProfile entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Comment: Have you dropped the old table structure before adding tablePerHierarchy false?

Comment: Actually in my Datasource.groovy file for development i am using create-drop and each time when server starts db structure recreated

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Михаил's great answer, two separate things worked for me.

1. Putting the base domain class in src

This worked best for me because both the constraints from the base class and the subclass were applied. Having not null columns in the subclasses was important for my use case. However, it appears that only the mapping block from the subclass is used.

2. Using `tablePerConcreteClass true`

An advantage here is it allows an index to be declared in the BaseDomain class that then appears in each of the subclass tables, ie both the mapping blocks from the base class and subclass are used. Only the constraints in the base class appear to be used.

```
abstract class BaseDomain {
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false  // avoid creating the base_domain table
        tablePerConcreteClass true
        id generator: 'increment' // https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10849
        someColumnInBaseDomain index: true  // index this column in each subclass table
    }
}
```