# Grails Table Per class work around issues

Tags: hibernate, grails

I recently posted an [answer on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447280/equivalent-of-inheritancetype-table-per-class-in-grails/45209432#45209432) which appeared to be working. The tests that had been done was all creation of new records.

Since implementing it I found that whilst creation of new records was fine, attempting to edit existing entries all led back to original record.
According to Hibernate (Even) looking at object in Controller the version was 1. I changed above answer to include versions (either way off or on)
with it on the version was 1 the get request from hibernate showed the latest name change but on listing and even looking up mysql db the version was 0 the last updated was when created and entry was as was.

After hours of chasing around changing transaction types attempting to change id generator and nothing appeared to work.

The only thing that in the end has worked was to put the extended object elements back into original classes and not extend from src/main

So in effect repetition of all the entries in all the classes (what I was trying to centralise) by this work around for table per class.

As I say creation of new records absolutely wonderful but edit some oddness

Since I always tell others this, it was done on grails 3.2.8 but I have modified gorm to use `gormVersion=6.1.4.RELEASE`

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion}"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
```

Since the question wasn't clear to clarify the actual problem:

Given we have this scenario:

```
package test

abstract class Tester {
    String name
    String something

    static mapping = {
        tablePerConcreteClass true
        id generator: 'increment'
        version false
    }
}
```

Next out actual domain classes in `grails-app/domains/test`:

```
package  test
class Tester1 extends Tester {
}
```

and

```
package  test
class Tester2 extends Tester {
}
```

On the first attempt to generate any given record i.e. a brand new record:

```
  Tester2 tester=new Tester2()
   tester.name='something'
   //This works
   tester.save()
   //If I now attempt to reload the object (assuming a re-edit of a given entry)
   Tester2 t = Tester2.get(tester.id)  // Tester2.read(tester.id) //Tester2.load(tester.id)
  t.name="something new"
  t.save() //t.save(flush:true)
  //on the application it shows at this exact point
   assert t.name=='something new' //This is correct at this point
  //println "${t.version} shows version 1"
```

Trying to relist the object shows old data. Looking at actual DB version is 0 update time is when it was created not updated and data is still old original value `something` and not `something new` as set on second update.

I tried a variety of ways and creation no issues but trying to load existing object to update it from this model always showed the original saved object not the updated object.

By moving the name object from extended src file back into domain class and no longer extending the src file actually then made updates work

#### Update I have narrowed down issue to a bug within 6.1.4.RELEASE

By 6.1.4 I mean  `gradle.properties`:

```
gormVersion=6.1.4.RELEASE
```

Please review the changes in this project:https://github.com/vahidhedayati/tableperclass/commit/30a78ab08b0dfaa3721d0d4e30dd31588aa08279

it shows after this change I saw odd behaviour 
It is all explained here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/tableperclass/blob/master/README.md

#### Updated Update

Tried 6.1.5 and same fate as 6.1.4 so far as test goes (as in issue remains) updated github project with gorm version

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Is there a problem, or a question?