# Grails GORM Inheritance changing discriminator column

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'd like to use an Enum or String in place of column class to map on table inheritance in Grails.

For exemple

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("USR")
@DiscriminatorColumn(length = 3, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, columnDefinition = "CHAR(3) NOT NULL", name = "type")
public class People implements Serializable {
```

I couldn't find a way to change it into documentation.

Comment: Does people extend anything or anything extending people ? unsure if you mean you wish to change class People to enum people in which case don't think so . You can declare an enum and set ordinalType the discrimiator is usually you set in mapping to define an override value of table name so far as hibernate mapping of table extension goes

Answer (score 0):

Going to try to answer your question but in all honesty unsure where your point is wavering towards since it is left  open ended as to to the actual question raised Inheritance and there appears to be no signs of inheritance on example provided.

My first pointer would [be here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264247/grails-table-per-class-work-around-issues).

This does work or had it working on default grails 3.2.8 but upon updates to latest gorm there was issues with updating existing records. I gave up and did it as separate classes at the time.

If your question relates to having table per class then above setup is what you need for grails.

Typically you would do :

```
abstract class Something {
   static mapping = {
        cache true
        //tablePerConcreteClass false
        tablePerHierarchy false
       //discriminator value: 'institution'
   }
}

class SomethingElse  extends Something {
    static mapping={
        //discriminator value: 'somethingElse'
    }
}
```

The abstract class definition vs non abstract has different adverse effects into how your tables get created and how your whole model will then work. It all depends on the requirement.

The problem with above is when it comes to querying the class in HQL I faced a problem where when I tried to query instance.class I got a numeric number back from HQL rather than actual domainClass instance and obviously discriminator was first point of reach.

The actual trick in these extended classes is if in HQL something.class does not return actual class name to try

```
String query = """ select new map(type(s) as className,s.id as id) from Something s  """
```

The type(s) will now return actual string class name. (Maybe where you are stuck)

Usually you can do in HQL:

when `s.class = SomethingElse` then do something

and HQL will work out the actual className based on that matching domainClass name.

Somehow I don't think this is what you are after though