# GORM tablePerHierarchy doesn't create tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

I need to have two domains which are extends from one domain. However when i create the domains subdomains' tables are not created.

```
class BaseEntity {
  Date created
  Boolean isDeleted
  Date modified
  Integer version

  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
    version false
    table name: "base_entity",  schema: "user"
    isDeleted defaultValue: Boolean.FALSE
  }
}
```

First domain extends from BaseEntity

```
class UserEx extends BaseEntity {
  String firstName
  String lastName
  String password
  String userName

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table name: "user_ex",  schema: "user"
  }
}
```

This is the second domain

```
class UserType extends BaseEntity {
  Integer name

  static belongsTo = [parent: UserType]
  static hasMany = [child:UserType]

  static mapping = {
    version false
    table name: "user_type",  schema: "user"
  }
}
```

In the db the only created table is BaseEntity. If i remove tablePerHierarchy property from BaseEntity domain, created table(which is BaseEntity) contains all fields of userEx and userType - this is not we like to have-

To sum up I want to have those three tables in my db without losing extends relationship.

Thanks in advance

Comment: tablePerHierarchy false 'should' be triggering new tables to be created.  Maybe a silly question but are the subclasses also in the grails-app/domain folder, you haven't put them under src have you?

Comment: @Dave :D they are also in domain folder. I am using IntelliJ so it is hard to make that mistake :D

Comment: :-) had to ask the obvious.   Have you tried with a clean database? What is your dbCreate parameter set to in datasource.groovy?

Comment: @Dave yes. i also tried to change db from postgresql to oracle.. dbCreate parameter is set to 'update'

Comment: Do you need the 'table' lines?  I've never needed to use these, and also wondering why you have an actionPriority in the mapping but no actionProperty field defined.  Likewise with the deleted entry in UserEx.   Can you confirm the UserEx & UserType tables aren't being created at all?

Comment: @Dave ooh. sorry for that i tried to shorten the text. I use them always because in the project some tables should be in different schemas and sometimes auto generated table names are kind of pucky. Let me try without them. Yes they are not created at all..

Comment: I feel like the DB is hanging onto an old schema, even if tables are recreated,  I'd start totally fresh with a new DB.  Not sure there's anything else I can suggest I'm afraid.

Comment: try to add tablePerConcreteClass=true, @see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790657/how-grails-gorm-will-insert-table-per-concrete-class-where-each-concrete-class-i#24561515